# Is it possible to create a private Q&A site using the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api

I want to create a sort of private Q&A site to allow university students of the same courses to communicate. Is it possible by using the Stack Exchange API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the API only allows you to connect to existing Stack Exchange sites, and Stack Exchange no longer sells public-facing sites. [Stack Overflow Enterprise is available](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use, but it is really meant for larger organizations only.

It looks like you want one of [the clones listed on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones).

---

Since it's not clear which, if any, of those clones offer an API, there is another approach...

If you submit your site through [the Area 51 proposal process](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and it goes to beta, then you can access the new site through the API.  It won't be private, but you could potentially get a lot more people helping as well.

Comment: I added another possibility to your answer rather than create my own half-duplicate answer.  If you object, then I apologize and you can revert the edit.

Comment: I do not object!  You're making the internet a better place with the only possible issue being that we have a different allocation of fake internet points, about which I don't really care.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can now use *Stack Overflow for Teams* to create a private Q&A site with all the Stack-Overflowy goodness. (Plus an "ask" pinging feature suitable for closed/private organizations.)

See [the Teams landing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) and note that they do have an educational discount:

> **Do you offer special pricing to nonprofit organizations and educational institutions?**
>
> Yes, [contact us](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new) to learn about our special pricing structure.

For more information see [the *stack-overflow-for-teams* tag on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams).

[Teams do have API support](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams), although it is read-only at the moment.